# android fragment getArguments returns null in oncreateView()

Tags: android, null, return, arguments, fragment

I have two fragments and `FilterFragment` and `LocationListFragment`. when I am switching to `LocationListFragment.java` I am getting values in `getArguments()` and from `LocationListFragment.java` to `FilterFragment.java` getting null values by calling `getArgument()`; here is the details

In `FilterFargment.java` code is here for set values:

```
  LocationListFragment locationListFragment = new LocationListFragment();
             bundle = new Bundle();
            Log.e("",""+locationList.getLocationListFilter().size());
            bundle.putParcelable(Constant.LOCATION_LIST_FILTER, locationList);
            bundle.putString(Constant.FROM_DATE_FILTER, textView_time_from.getText().toString());
            locationListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ((DashbordActivity) getActivity()).switchFragment(locationListFragment, true);
```

In `LocationListFragment.java` (getting values)

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        locationList = args.getParcelable(Constant.LOCATION_LIST_FILTER);
        getFromDate = args.getString(Constant.FROM_DATE_FILTER);}}
```

And here from `LocationListFragment` on button click send data to `FilterFragment` sending new values with bundle:

```
FilterFragment filterFragment =new FilterFragment();//.newInstance(getFromDate, getEndDate, getLocation, getCategories);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constant.FROM_DATE_FILTER, getFromDate);
    bundle.putString(Constant.WHERE_FILTER, getLocation);
    filterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((DashbordActivity) getActivity()).switchFragment(filterFragment, true);
```

and in `FilterFragment.java` while returning back getting **null** value for `getArguments();` code is here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter, container, false);
    Log.e("FilterFragment", "oncreateview");

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    Log.e("getArguments", "" + getArguments());//getting null here
```

Also, I have used this method for switching fragment,

```
    public void switchFragment(BaseFragment fragment, boolean keep) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName(), 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()) == null) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.

        FragmentTransaction tr = manager.beginTransaction();

        tr.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

        if (keep) {
            tr.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
       Log.e("keep", "BaseAct:" + keep);
        }
        tr.commit();
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Cant find anything wrong with your code, i have a similar implementation working properly, can you check the getArguments() value just after calling setArguments?

Comment: i have also tried by fragment newInstance(String parm1,String Param2) also. but in this case on FilterListFragment it get values from parameters but after set bundle argument. and getting values in onCreateView() by getArgument() shows null. link of same Problem is here [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/issues/38)

Comment: yes that position i am getting values of argument @Nanoc

Comment: Then maybe you are showing a different instance of the fragment?

Comment: still not able to solved that problem thats the code mention above what should i change can you tell me? @Nanoc

Comment: @JDenais can you help me i have seen your answer but not getting [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669503/fragment-shows-twice-on-top-of-eachother)